# SQL with GROUP BY and ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

I am trying to display posts from a table grouped by certain meta values from another table, and ordered by other meta values or post id if "recent" order is selected.

The best I came up with is:

```
SELECT `posts`.`id_post`, 
       m1.value AS REGIUNE, 
       m2.value AS JUDET, 
       m3.value AS LOCALITATE, 
       MAX(`posts`.`id_post`) AS ORDERBY 
FROM `posts`
INNER JOIN `posts_meta` m1
    ON(`posts`.`id_post`=m1.`id_post`)
INNER JOIN `posts_meta` m2
    ON(`posts`.`id_post`=m2.`id_post`)
INNER JOIN `posts_meta` m3
    ON(`posts`.`id_post`=m3.`id_post`)
WHERE
    `posts`.`type` = 'published'
AND ( m1.`meta` = 'regiune' )
AND ( m2.`meta` = 'judet' )
AND ( m3.`meta` = 'localitate' )
GROUP BY  posts.id_post
ORDER BY ORDERBY DESC
```

This however only works if we are not grouping by any meta value (m1.value, m2.value or m3.value).

Comment: Can you post some sample data and desired results? Your're more likely to get an answer if you do that...

Comment: @Adrian here is a link to what i am trying to get and what i am getting : [link](http://img214.imageshack.us/img214/6563/aseqi.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This one should work...

```
SELECT `posts`.`id_post`, 
       m1.value AS REGIUNE, 
       m2.value AS JUDET, 
       m3.value AS LOCALITATE, 
       MAX(`posts`.`id_post`) AS ORDERBY 
FROM `posts`
INNER JOIN `posts_meta` m1
    ON(`posts`.`id_post`=m1.`id_post`)
INNER JOIN `posts_meta` m2
    ON(`posts`.`id_post`=m2.`id_post`)
INNER JOIN `posts_meta` m3
    ON(`posts`.`id_post`=m3.`id_post`)
WHERE
    `posts`.`type` = 'published'
AND ( m1.`meta` = 'regiune' )
AND ( m2.`meta` = 'judet' )
AND ( m3.`meta` = 'localitate' )
GROUP BY  1,2,3,4
ORDER BY `posts`.`id_post` DESC
```

Comment: that still doesn't work, as i am only getting first post from every group, instead of the last one :(

Comment: Which database are you using and what's the error you are facing?

Comment: i am using MySQL, and using your code returns for every join a row instead of grouping them togheter. Here is an [example](http://img214.imageshack.us/img214/6563/aseqi.jpg) of the rows i get from grouping by m1.value.